# How to override CSS or re-skin for node_module?

Tags: css, angular, node-modules

I have a node_module https://github.com/Alberplz/angular2-color-picker
that I am using in my angular 2 project, but as all modules it includes it's CSS files and if I do inspect element i see in listed as localhost, but can't actually locate where they are.

I could create a separate file and overwrite but than I making a bigger mess as putting CSS on top of CSS and I would like to re skin the module.

This is how the CSS looks now
[image]

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the steps I understand to overwrite a module is to:

1. Fork the github environment locally
2. Git clone your forked enviorment
3. Register on npm
4. Apply changes to your local and publish on npm under different name
5. Npm install the published npm pacakage.

Comment: worst way to do that... just for a couple of css files creating a new project means a goodbye the future releases of that project, which is more worth.

Comment: Do it right and staying up to date is as simple as a pull request. Only con is that you're adding to the list of things you maintain.

Answer (score 1):

If you look into the repository of that project you can locate style [here](https://github.com/Alberplz/angular2-color-picker/blob/master/src/templates/default/color-picker.scss#L23...L32).
The compiled style is imported to directive [here](https://github.com/Alberplz/angular2-color-picker/blob/0dd5125675e10749ae879895595a52fc3d3ce16a/src/color-picker.directive.ts#L203). I don't see any example of changing color picker style other than [this options](https://github.com/Alberplz/angular2-color-picker#options).

If you want to override the style you might have to use some "shadow DOM breaking" solution or global style that will override it with more specific selector, eventually an `!important` keyword.

Comment: !important keyword. is what i am worried about as that's bad practice :(

Comment: If you don't want to override the styles, you can also fork the project on Github, adjust it to your needs and then import it like `npm install --save https://github.com/{author}/{repo}/{branch}`

Comment: yep, what I said on my answear :)

Comment: What did you mean by "shadow DOM breaking" ?

Comment: Either a global style sheet with selector specific enough to not break anything else or with angular you can use `/deep/ .selector` to style element ignoring the shadow DOM from component style.

Answer (score 1):

This component is extended in the ngx set of components (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-color-picker[ngx-color-picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-color-picker)) and I have been able to set styling by overriding style in a  tag in the Index.html in Angular 5 application. The style tag must be below the body tag