# Override Angular Material Component

Tags: angular, npm, drop-down-menu, components, angular-material

I want to override the Angular Material select component (https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview) so that I can change the appearance of the now input-field to an icon button for example. I want to do this because it should somehow work as a dropdown.

I already tried the overriding of the select and the component works very well like this. I saw in this answer: [How to override CSS or re-skin for node_module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42893632/how-to-override-css-or-re-skin-for-node-module) that I would need to create a new npm package and publish it. But the select is part of the Material package which is inside the @angular package.

So should I fork the whole Material project or can I just create a new package for this one part? But if I have both integrated (Material and my expanded select package) I don't think it would use the overwritten one.

I know that it is not really recommended to do such things and instead use something else which is better maintained. To explain you why I want to do this: We are on a very old version of Angular. We currently use ng2-bootstrap for the dropdown, as Material doesn't offer a dropdown component. But the ngx-bootstrap dropdown is very laggy in its most current version and it is blocking our Angular upgrade. Also we would like to get rid of ngx-bootstrap and just use Material.

Comment: Why not instead using a mat-menu component to render a dropdown onclick of an icon button? https://material.angular.io/components/menu/examples

Comment: thank you, i will try this, if it fits our needs.

Comment: It would definitely be easier to refactor you UI than to refactor/expand a third party component. Gl

Answer (score 1):

Use ViewEncapsulation and set None For example:-

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  encapsulation:ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

Any css written in app.component.css will override Angular material css

Comment: Or better yet, use `styles.css` which are meant for global stylesheets.